# Can you spend willpower on hunger dice?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Can you spend willpower on hunger dice?

I am extremely confused. Because on page 122, under Willpower, it says:

> Characters may not spend willpower to re-roll Hunger dice

But on page 205, it says:

> If the Hunger complication seems too dangerous in the moment, the player can (and should) opt to re-roll by spending Willpower (p. 122), either to get rid of regular 0's to defuse a messy critical or to turn a failed roll into a success in the case of a bestial failure

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7):

You use the Willpower to reroll the other, non-Hunger Dice in the pool. To emphasize:

> If the Hunger complication seems too dangerous in the moment, the player can (and should) opt to **re-roll by spending Willpower** (p. 122), either to **get rid of regular 10's** to defuse a messy critical or to **turn a failed roll into a success** in the case of a bestial failure.

Comment: Okay thank you. Another question.
On page 212 there is a table about hunger slaking. First it says Max non-harmful drink 1-2
Below it says harmful drink 1-4 and then that the DC is equal to hunger slaked.
Below that it says 5 and it's a dead human.
How many can you slake from one human?
Also it confuses me with the 2 maximum non-harmful takes a scene and draining a human completely takes only 5 turns?

Comment: @AlexanderLuigianaLarsen That should really be another question, which I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: Okay I'll make it as another question :)

Comment: The related question is here: [How does slaking hunger work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150794/how-does-slaking-hunger-work)