# How does slaking hunger work?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I was reading about slaking hunger and the table on page 212, and there are several things which confuse me.

First, it says that you can slake 1-2 hunger without risk of harming the human. Staking 1 sip takes three turns and slakes 1 hunger, and slaking 2 hunger takes a scene.
Then down below it says that you can slake 1-4 hunger harmfully and it takes one turn per hunger slaked, and that the mortal must make a Str + Stam check with a DC equal to the hunger slaked.
Then at the bottom it says slaking 5 hunger kills a human.

I have a few questions. The thing that confuses me the most is that one sip, slaking 1 hunger, takes 3 turns - but down below, it says slaking 1 hunger takes one turn. Does that mean I have to slake 3 hunger before it becomes deadly? Or is it if you want to feed quickly and do it forcefully that it becomes dangerous? If I slake 2 points recklessly, then the mortal takes 2 aggravated damage, but does it put him in immediate danger?

What if I slake 3 hunger? If I slake 3 hunger then what is the difficulty for the mortal to survive? 3 or 1?

What is the maximum hunger I can slake from a mortal?

It also says on page 213 under bite attacks that for each blood slaked from a mortal, it deals 1 aggravated damage per turn and slakes one hunger per turn, whereas in the table on page 212, it says the first hunger slaked takes 3 turns and doesn't deal damage.

Answer (score 6):

1. Your second guess is correct. If you are feeding carefully, making sure not to harm the mortal, then it takes longer. If you are feeding aggressively, it's faster, and you put the mortal at risk of dying. You can take 1 or 2 points either safely or recklessly. If you slake 2 points recklessly, you deal 2 aggravated damage and the mortal must make a difficulty 2 check (Stamina + Survival) to survive the blood loss.
2. If you slake 3 hunger, you are placing the human in danger and risking their death. They take 3 aggravated damage and must make a difficulty 3 check to survive. There is no way to slake 3 hunger in one feeding from one person that doesn't put them at risk of death.
3. The maximum hunger you can slake from a human is 5. Doing so kills that mortal. This is the only way to remove your last hunger die.
4. That's for using your bite as a Brawl-based attack. It's a different sort of bite.

Comment: So that means if I slake 2 points recklessly then the mortal takes 2 aggravated damage, but it doesn't put him in immediate danger?
And if I slake 3 hunger then what is the difficulty for the mortal to survive? 3 or 1?

Comment: @AlexanderLuigianaLarsen I worked those answers into the main body.